How to modify this regex to add up all digits to a number?
I have this regex which checks if the password has one digit at least.
^(?=.*[0-9]).{6,}$
How do I modify the regex to check if the sum of all the digits in the password is equal to say 10.
So this string should match "dhbqdw46". This shouldn't "jwhf1ejhjh0".

Is that possible?

This is not possible with regex. You need to get all numbers and do the addition yourself.

You can't do that with a RegEx. It's not designed to do that. You should write some JavaScript code to calcluate the sum of values. You could however use RegEx to match and extract all numbers/ digits from the string, which you can then add up.

Matching "A B C" where A + B = C has been proven to be possible. You are welcome to try to follow the author's steps, though that might not be very easy.

@InSync, are you suggesting a largish alternation: 10 digits present, all 1's, 9 digits present, eight 1's and one 2, ..., 3 digits present, one 5, one 3 and one 2 two, ...?

@CarySwoveland I wasn't, though that would be a solution too, yes.

This can be easily done in any language. In Ruby, for example:  str.each_char.grep(/\d/).sum(&:to_i) == 10.

Regular expressions are designed for pattern matching and cannot perform arithmetic operations like calculating the sum of digits.
As mentioned in the comments, you'll need to implement the logic yourself. Since you've tagged this question with JavaScript, here's a solution using JavaScript:


function isValidPassword(password, targetSum){
  const digits = password.match(/\d/g) || [];
  const sum = digits.reduce((sum, digit) => sum + parseInt(digit, 10), 0);
  return sum === targetSum
}


const password1 = "dhbqdw46";
const password2 = "jwhf1ejhjh0";

console.log(isValidPassword(password1, 10));  // Output: true
console.log(isValidPassword(password2, 10));  // Output: false




As pointed out in the comments, validating that all digits in a string add up to a number is best done by aggregating numbers in a looping construct.
But as a proof of concept, we can use a PCRE/PCRE2-compatible regex engine, which supports separate subroutine definitions, to systematically match what you want.
The idea is to match digits totalling 10 as digits totalling 1 followed by digits totalling 9, or digits totalling 9 followed by digits totalling 1, or digits totalling 2 followed by digits totalling 8, or digits totalling 8 followed by digits totalling 2, and so on.
And digits totalling 9 is defined by 9 followed by digits totalling 0, or digits totalling 0 followed by 9, or digits totalling 1 followed by digits totalling 8, or digits totalling 8 followed by digits totalling 1, and so on.
Such definitions of groups of digits totalling to a specific number go on, until we define digits totalling 0, which is just zero or more groups of possibly-non-digit-separated 0s.
So your regex, which includes a validation of 6 or more characters, can be modified as follows:
(?(DEFINE)(?'t0'(?:\D*0)*))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t1'(\D*1)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t2'(\D*2)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1){2}))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t3'(\D*3)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t2)|(?P>t2)(?P>t1)))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t4'(\D*4)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t3)|(?P>t3)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2){2}))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t5'(\D*5)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t4)|(?P>t4)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t3)|(?P>t3)(?P>t2)))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t6'(\D*6)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t5)|(?P>t5)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t4)|(?P>t4)(?P>t2)|(?P>t3){2}))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t7'(\D*7)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t6)|(?P>t6)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t5)|(?P>t5)(?P>t2)|(?P>t3)(?P>t4)|(?P>t4)(?P>t3)))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t8'(\D*8)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t7)|(?P>t7)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t6)|(?P>t6)(?P>t2)|(?P>t3)(?P>t5)|(?P>t5)(?P>t3)|(?P>t4){2}))
(?(DEFINE)(?'t9'(\D*9)(?P>t0)|(?P>t0)(?-1)|(?P>t1)(?P>t8)|(?P>t8)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t7)|(?P>t7)(?P>t2)|(?P>t3)(?P>t6)|(?P>t6)(?P>t3)|(?P>t4)(?P>t5)|(?P>t5)(?P>t4)))
^(?=(?:(?P>t1)(?P>t9)|(?P>t9)(?P>t1)|(?P>t2)(?P>t8)|(?P>t8)(?P>t2)|(?P>t3)(?P>t7)|(?P>t7)(?P>t3)|(?P>t4)(?P>t6)|(?P>t6)(?P>t4)|(?P>t5){2})\D*$).{6,}

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/4wjgRG/2
You can then use a library like pcre2-wasm to match with a PCRE2 pattern in JavaScript.

@CarySwoveland This is because the OP also has a requirement of matching 6 or more characters ("How do I modify the regex...", where the regex has such a requirement).

RegEx can't do that or more precisely (since there are some hacky/ overly complex ways to do it) is certainly not meant to do that. To check this kind of stuff you should write your own JavaScript.
If you want you can use regex to extract all digits from the string and then sum them up using JavaScript (See Variant 1) or you just use JavaScript and do not use regex at all (See Variant 2).
Variant 1


/**
 * Matches all digits in the password and returns them as an array of numbers.
 * @param {string} password
 * @returns all digits in the string as an array of numbers
 */
const matchAllDigits = (password) =>
  [...password.matchAll(/\d/g)].map((x) => parseInt(x[0]));

/**
 * Sum up all numbers in the array.
 * @param {number[]} nums numbers to sum up
 * @returns total sum of all numbers
 */
const sumOfDigits = (nums) => nums.reduce((acc, num) => acc + num, 0);

/**
 * Return true if sum of digits matches provides sum, otherwise false.
 * @param {string} password password to check
 * @param {number} sum sum of digits to check for (default 10)
 * @returns
 */
const hasSumOfDigits = (password, sum = 10) =>
  sumOfDigits(matchAllDigits(password)) === sum;

console.log(hasSumOfDigits("dhbqdw46")); // true
console.log(hasSumOfDigits("jwhf1ejhjh0")); // false



Variant 2


const isDigit = (character) =>
  typeof character === "string" &&
  character.length === 1 &&
  character >= "0" &&
  character <= "9";

/**
 * Return true if sum of digits matches provides sum, otherwise false.
 * @param {string} password password to check
 * @param {number} sum sum of digits to check for (default 10)
 * @returns
 */
const hasSumOfDigits = (password, sum = 10) => {
  let index = 0;
  let currentSum = 0;
  const chars = password.split("");
  // Loop through all characters in password as long as sum is not already exceeded
  while (index < chars.length && currentSum <= sum) {
    const currentChar = chars[index];
    if (isDigit(currentChar)) {
      // if character is digit, add it to current sum
      currentSum += parseInt(currentChar);
    }
    // go to next character
    index++;
  }
  // return true if sum of digits match provided sum, otherwise false
  return currentSum === sum;
};

console.log(hasSumOfDigits("dhbqdw46")); // true
console.log(hasSumOfDigits("jwhf1ejhjh0")); // false




Please note: this answer is only concerned with the requirement of summing up to 10, not all the other requirements you might have for the password, which could be handled by a separate RegEx or again via some custom JavaScript.


Here is a way that could be done, with the understanding that I have addressed the question of whether it is possible to use a regular expression to achieve the desired result. I certainly would not advocate this approach.
I count 38 ways that digits 1 through 9 can sum to 10. For example, the sixth row in the table below uses five 1's, one 2, one 3 and any number of zeroes.
   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  ----------------------------------
  10
   8   1
   7       1
   6   2
   6           1
 > 5   1   1
   5               1
   4   3
   4   1       1
   4       2
   4                   1
   3   2   1
   3   1           1
   3       1   1
   3                       1 

   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
  ----------------------------------
   2   4
   2   2       1
   2   1               1
   2       1       1
   2                           1
   1   3   1
   1   2           1          
   1   1   1   1
   1   1                   1
   1       3
   1       1           1
   1           1   1
   1                               1
       3       1
       2       2
       2               1
       1   1       1
       1       2
       1                       1
           2   1
           1               1
               1       1
                   2

We may require one of these to be present by crafting a regular expression with an alternation having 38 components:
^(?=.{6})(?:...|...|......|...)

The positive lookahead (?=.{6}) requires the string to have at least six characters.
For example, the 6th alternation element (requiring five 1's, one 2, one 3 and any number of zeroes) can be written as follows.
(?=[^1]*(?:1[^1]*){5}$)(?=[^2]*2[^2]*$)(?=[^3]*3[^3]*$)(?!.*[456789]) 

Demo
This regular expression can be broken down as follows.
(?=          # begin a positive lookahead
  [^1]*      # match zero of more characters other than '1'
  (?:1[^1]*) # match '1' followed by zero or more characters
             # other than '1' and save to a non-capture group
  {5}        # execute the non-capture group 5 times
  $          # match end of string
)            # end positive lookahead 
(?=          # begin a positive lookahead
  [^2]*      # match zero of more characters other than '2'
  2          # match '2'
  [^2]*      # match zero of more characters other than '2'
  $          # match end of string
)            # end positive lookahead 
(?=          # begin a positive lookahead
  [^3]*      # match zero of more characters other than '3'
  3          # match '3'
  [^3]*      # match zero of more characters other than '3'
  $          # match end of string
)            # end positive lookahead 
(?!          # begin a negative lookahead
.*[456789]   # match zero or more characters other than line
             # terminators followed by a digit contained in
             # the character class
)            # end negative lookahead 
     

